# Can I tell if identity insert is on or off in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm running SQL Server 2019 Developer edition. One bit of code I've been handed does:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT (tablename) OFF
```

If this is already turned off, I get an error and it stops running. Is there a way to test this value first? I looked in:

```
SELECT * 
FROM SYS.IDENTITY_COLUMNS 
WHERE OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(object_id) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) = '(tablename)'
```

... but this does not seem to reveal the current state.

Comment: I guess the "only" way is to do it through TRY/CATCH, but if you need to know, it means you're not in control of your inserts. Using identity_insert ON is a bad idea for ongoing work in my opinion. Why do you need identity at all if you're explicitely setting it?

Comment: You can repeat ``set identity_insert table_name off;`` or ``set identity_insert table_name on;`` several times consecutively. This does not cause an error. Maybe you have another problem.